# Configure webXml in IntelliJ maven-war-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

In the Maven Projects tools window, I see that the maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 is installed but this is grayed out.  When I run the war:war goal, I get the following warning:

> [INFO] Building war:
>   C:\Users\Klaus\IdeaProjects\JerseyTestRestWebApp\target\tut-test-rest-api.war
>   [WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which
>   will be ignored  (webxml attribute is missing from war task, or
>   ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true

I am using IntelliJ 14.1.  How does one go about setting this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this as your build configuration and it should clear up the error your seeing.

```
 <project>
        ...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        ...
    </project>
```

Comment: That was the missing bit.  Did not find this in IntelliJ doc.  Thx.

Comment: Yeah this was more a maven issue so all this pom trickery is documented there. Glad it worked for you!